# MSMessageLayout has no member caption in iMessage App

Tags: ios, swift, imessage

I'm trying to access the details within a selectedMessage MSMessage... however, when I try to access caption, it gives the error:

" Value of type 'MSMessageLayout?' has no member 'caption' "

This is how I try to access it:

```
self.conversation?.selectedMessage?.layout.caption
```

Is it even possible to access messages like this? I was thinking that selectedMessage would only be non-nil if it was a message my application sent, and if it was a message my application sent, it would have a caption (because my messages always will have captions).

****edit****

I tried to cast layout as MSMessageTemplateLayout because it has the caption attribute:

```
let layout = self.conversation?.selectedMessage?.layout as! MSMessageTemplateLayout
```

but when I did that, i got a runtime unwrapping of a nil... even though I KNOW the message I selected and sent has a layout.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like Apple intentionally makes the layout nil... and that's annoying: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/53174

HOWEVER, I think I found a workaround by storing the same message I send in the 'layout' attribute in the 'url' attribute. This 'url' attribute of MSMessage remains intact and accessible.